# Applying OUTER JOIN in Oracle

Tags: oracle, outer-join

After creating 3 tables, equip_type, output_history and time_history.
This code is to show, for each row output_history, the most recent data in time_history.
And result is look like this.

```
 EQUIP MODEL DATE1  QUANTITY   DATE2   TIME  EQUIP_TYPE
 ---- ---- ---------- ------  -------- ----  ----------
  e1    m1  20180103  10      20180101   6    A
  e1    m1  20180106  20      20180105   5    A
```

But How could I modify code to show the row which have no equip_type, like this.

```
EQUIP MODEL DATE1  QUANTITY   DATE2   TIME  EQUIP_TYPE
 ---- ---- ---------- ------  -------- ----  ----------
  e1    m1  20180103  10      20180101   6    A
  e1    m1  20180106  20      20180105   5    A
  e2    m1  20180106  20      20180105   5   (null)
  e3    m1  20180106  20      (null)  (null) (null)
```

Code is as below;

```
 CREATE TABLE equip_type  (  
      EQUIP_TYPE VARCHAR(15),    
      EQUIP VARCHAR(15)
      );
    INSERT INTO equip_type  VALUES ('A','e1');
    CREATE TABLE output_history (  
      EQUIP VARCHAR(15),     
      MODEL VARCHAR(15),     
      Data1 VARCHAR(15),        
      QUANTITY  NUMBER(10) 
      );
    INSERT INTO output_history VALUES ('e1','m1','20180103',10);
    INSERT INTO output_history VALUES ('e1','m1','20180106',20);
    INSERT INTO output_history VALUES ('e2','m1','20180106',20);
    INSERT INTO output_history VALUES ('e3','m1','20180106',20);
    CREATE TABLE time_history (  
      EQUIP VARCHAR(15),     
      MODEL VARCHAR(15),       
      Data2 VARCHAR(15),    
      time NUMBER(10)
      );
    INSERT INTO time_history VALUES ('e1','m1','20180101',6);
    INSERT INTO time_history VALUES ('e1','m1','20180105',5);
    INSERT INTO time_history VALUES ('e2','m1','20180106',5); --added

SELECT
    o.equip,
    o.model,
    o.data1,
    o.quantity,
    t.data2,
    t.time,
    e.equip_type
FROM 
    output_history o
    INNER JOIN equip_type e ON e.equip = o.equip    --I have tried RIGHT OUTER JOIN here, but didn' work
    INNER JOIN time_history t ON t.equip = o.equip AND t.data2 <= o.data1
    AND t.data2 >= '20180101' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM time_history
    WHERE 
        equip = o.equip
        AND data2 <= o.data1
        AND data2 > t.data2
        AND data2 >= '20180101' AND data2 <= '2080106' 
)AND o.data1 >= '20180101' AND o.data1 <= '20180106';
```

Comment: have you tried using LEFT JOIN on "INNER JOIN equip_type e ON e.equip = o.equip"

Comment: There is no `e2` in `time_history` so it's unclear why you would expect date2 to be `20180105` for `e2`

Comment: @Peter Paff I've just added one row that I have ommitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is infact a double outjoin you need, both the equipment and the time_history are missing the equip "e2" records.

But this should work. (note the special oracle outer join syntax)

```
SELECT
    o.equip,
    o.model,
    o.data1,
    o.quantity,
    t.data2,
    t.time,
    e.equip_type
FROM 
    output_history o, equip_type e, time_history t 
WHERE 
    o.equip = e.equip (+)
    AND o.equip = t.equip
    AND o.model = t.model
    AND t.data2 = (select max(data2) from time_history where equip = o.equip and model = o.model and data2 < o.data1)
UNION        
SELECT
    o.equip,
    o.model,
    o.data1,
    o.quantity,
    null,
    null,
    e.equip_type
FROM 
    output_history o, equip_type e
WHERE 
    o.equip = e.equip (+)
    AND NOT exists (select 1 from time_history where equip = o.equip and model = o.model)
;
```

Also note

```
AND t.data2 = (select max(data2) from time_history where equip = o.equip and model = o.model and data2 < o.data1)
```

This is a general approach when you want to join to the most recent but previous record. But it is not possible in an outer join. That's why the part after the UNION is needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    o.equip,
    o.model,
    o.data1,
    o.quantity,
    t.data2,
    t.time,
    e.equip_type
FROM 
    output_history o
    LEFT JOIN equip_type e ON e.equip = o.equip    
    LEFT JOIN time_history t ON t.equip = o.equip AND t.data2 <= o.data1
    AND t.data2 >= '20180101' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM time_history
    WHERE 
        equip = o.equip
        AND data2 <= o.data1
        AND data2 > t.data2
        AND data2 >= '20180101' AND data2 <= '2080106' 
)AND o.data1 >= '20180101' AND o.data1 <= '20180106' ORDER BY equip, quantity;
```